# read xml file to list of string

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have a xml file contains data like below..

[image]

and I need to read this file and populate the array each element must be comma seperated string of xml element:
["Adana,01,Aladağ,01720", "Adana,01,Aladağ,01920", "Adana,01,Aladağ,01930 "..]

This file contains many cities and codes so I need loop as efficient as it can be.

I read the file with this but its not seems fit as you guess;

```
   public List<string> readXmlToList(string filename)
    {
        List<string> lines = List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(filename);
        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            lines.Add(
            node.Attributes["City"].ToString()+"," 
            + node.Attributes["code"].ToString()+","
            + node.Attributes["name"].ToString()+","
            + node.Attributes["Zip"].ToString());
        }
        return lines;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XElement in order to make you what.It is easy.

```
//using System.Xml.Linq;
        XElement cities = XElement.Load("fileName");
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        foreach (var city in cities.Elements("City"))
        {
            StringBuilder cityInfo = new StringBuilder();
            cityInfo.Append(city.Attribute("name").Value + ",");
            cityInfo.Append(city.Attribute("no").Value + ",");
            foreach (var district in city.Elements("District"))
            {
                cityInfo.Append(district.Attribute("name").Value + ",");
                foreach (var zip in district.Elements("Zip"))
                {
                    cityInfo.Append(zip.Attribute("code").Value + ",");
                }
            }
            list.Add(cityInfo.ToString());
            cityInfo.Clear();
        }
        //do what you want with list
```